# Eclipse debug crash problems

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, crash

For some reason, I can hardly debug anything without Eclipse throwing up a crash error every other step.  I'm debugging Android on Eclipse 4.2. The error I get says:

```
'JDI Event Dispatch' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during: "JDI Event Dispatch".

An internal error occurred during: "JDI Event Dispatch".
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

In the Error Log, I get:

```
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.7.0_02
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

Error
Fri Mar 15 20:53:09 CDT 2013
An internal error occurred during: "JDI Event Dispatch".

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.MirrorImpl.defaultReplyErrorHandler(MirrorImpl.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.MethodImpl.bytecodes(MethodImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIMethod.isGetterMethod(JDIMethod.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread$StepHandler.locationIsFiltered(JDIThread.java:2559)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread$StepHandler.locationShouldBeFiltered(JDIThread.java:2525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread$StepHandler.handleEvent(JDIThread.java:2477)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.EventDispatcher.access$0(EventDispatcher.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.EventDispatcher$1.run(EventDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Also according to the Error Log, the error is taking place in the Plug-in `or.eclipse.core.jobs`.  Any help would be appreciated, I'm finding it very difficult to work without a debugger!

Comment: Do you happen to have anything in the "Expressions" tab of the debug window?

Comment: I just checked, and as a matter of fact there was something there!  I cleared it.  Could it really be that simple?  :)

Comment: It really could be. Give it a try. You can get errors if it is trying to do operations on things that aren't there such as trying to access something in a different class than what the debugger is actually in

Comment: Nope, I cleared it and started a new debug.  Got the error when I tried to take the first step.  :(

Answer (score 5):

I worked around these error by disabling step filtering. Seems like it was the filter simple getters option.

Comment: Solved this issue for me, having exactly the above stacktrace.

Comment: Because of that issue and 10 others I've switched to Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

It may have something to do with the name of the method. For example this method:

```
getFirstValueInBundles(String key, String defaultValue, Bundle... bundles) {
     ...
}
```

Causes the same exact stack trace on a step-in or step-over. Try changing the name of the method to something that doesn't use get...() :

```
firstValueInBundles(String key, String defaultValue, Bundle... bundles) {
     ...
}
```

Then method can be debugged normally.

If this fixes your problem, I will open a bug report and post its id here.

Comment: That seems to fix it for me.

Comment: The same refers to the methods starting with "set". For example: `setValue(int value) {...}` If you rename this method to `changeValue(int value) {...}` the error won't show up when enabling step filtering.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe a timeout issue in Eclipse. Here is a link to a [Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546190/jdi-event-dispatch-nullpointerexception). It looked like there was a bug report regarding this error through Eclipse's website but didn't seem to have any answers. I hope this can help you.

Since I mentioned the "expressions" tab, you can get JDI errors sometimes if you have certain expressions in there that Eclipse isn't able to deal with. While unrelated to your specific problem, it could be helpful to someone searching for something similar. [Here is a SO answer of mine regarding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818390/error-message-at-breakpoint-in-eclipse-jdi-thread-evaluations-has-encountered-a/14818809#14818809)